# jQuery: there is any way to select the "remaining area" outside a div...?

Tags: jquery

I have a script where i click an image to zoom it in, but i would the user to be able to click outside the image to close it.

i noticed though that if i set a function to the body

```
$(body).click(function{ closeImage(); })
```

is going ot be a conflict between that function and the regular function i created for the image (let's call it `openImage();` just for example's sake)...

there is any way to select the "remaining area" so it is the only portion of the screen that can fire `closeImage();` ?

UPDATE: to clarify my problem:  if i set a function on the boy and then i click the image, the image doesnt zoom anymore because it conflicts with the body function

Comment: can you show your HTML and JS?

Comment: my code is not really important...is just zoon function fired when user clicks an image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660633/detect-click-inside-outside-of-element-with-single-event-handler/4660691#4660691) for how to attach an event handler both to the body and the element, but cancel the event bubbling so that the body handler does not fire for particular sub-handlers.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly the function i was looking for!!

$(function(){
     $("body").click(function(e){
         if(e.target.id=="myDiv" || $(e.target).parents("#myDiv").size()){ 
              alert("inseide div");
         } else {
              alert("outside div");        
         }
     });
})

Answer (score 0):

I would rather put a "glass" on body, image on it (and of course bind click to that glass). Many sites does like that (also with non transparent glass).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(body + ':not(#imageID)').click(function{ closeImage(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `one()` so it automaticly unbind itself once fired.

http://api.jquery.com/one/