# How to dismiss a Twitter Bootstrap popover by clicking outside?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

Can we get popovers to be dismissable in the same way as modals, ie. make them close when user clicks somewhere outside of them?

Unfortunately I can't just use real modal instead of popover, because modal means position:fixed and that would be no popover anymore. :(

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8947749/1478467

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661543/5823517.  Doesn't involve looping through parents

Comment: `data-trigger="hover"` and `data-trigger="focus"` are built-in alternative for closing the popover, if you don't want to use toggle. In my opinion, `data-trigger="hover"` provides the best user experience...  there is no need to write extra .js code...

Answer (score 482, accepted):

**Update:** A slightly more robust solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/72/

For buttons containing text only:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    //did not click a popover toggle or popover
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

For buttons containing icons use **(this code has a bug in Bootstrap 3.3.6, see the fix below in this answer)**

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
        //did not click a popover toggle, or icon in popover toggle, or popover
        if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
            && $(e.target).parents('[data-toggle="popover"]').length === 0
            && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
        }
    });
```

**For JS Generated Popovers** Use `'[data-original-title]'` in place of `'[data-toggle="popover"]'`

**Caveat:** The solution above allows multiple popovers to be open at once.

**One popover at a time please:**

**Update:** Bootstrap 3.0.x, see code or fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/2/

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

This handles closing of popovers already open and not clicked on or their links have not been clicked.

---

**Update:** Bootstrap 3.3.6, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5GBU/1837/)

Fixes issue where after closing, takes 2 clicks to re-open

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"],[data-original-title]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {                
            (($(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover')||{}).inState||{}).click = false  // fix for BS 3.3.6
        }

    });
});
```

**Update:** Using the conditional of the previous improvement, this solution was achieved. Fix the problem of double click and ghost popover:

```
$(document).on("shown.bs.popover",'[data-toggle="popover"]', function(){
    $(this).attr('someattr','1');
});
$(document).on("hidden.bs.popover",'[data-toggle="popover"]', function(){
    $(this).attr('someattr','0');
});
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"],[data-original-title]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            if($(this).attr('someattr')=="1"){
                $(this).popover("toggle");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, consider 2 buttons next to each other. Each has the class popover-link so if you click both buttons, both popovers appear and overlap each other. However, if i click the second button, i want the first popover to disapear. but it wont, because both buttons are catchedbecause of 'popover-link. Is there some way to close each popover that dos not belong to the clicked popover-link or popover?

Comment: by the way, i extented your function: $('body').click(function (e) { 
        if ($('.popover, .popover-trigger').has(e.target).length === 0 && !$('.popover, .popover-trigger').is(e.target)) {
             $('.popover-trigger').popover('hide');
        }
    });

Comment: Cool man thanks, yea I wasn't too concerned about all the popovers being open because the last opened popover will always have the higher z index and you can just click outside to close them all... But I like your solution.

Comment: My revision handles open popups now, check it out.

Comment: @AlexSchneider thanks for your input, the is(e.target) was used here. The reason I only use the has(e.target) and length is because I always have icons inside a popover target container might revise my html

Comment: Thank you. Your code actually works with multiple instances of popovers on the same page. Thank you!!!

Comment: I attach to `$(document)` instead of `$('body')` since sometimes the `body` doesn't extend down the entire page.

Comment: For anyone using angular and bootstrap-ui who is trying to do the same thing, try $('.popover').prev().click(); I had trouble with .hide().

Comment: There is a bug in bootstrap v3.0.2 so `.popover('hide')` does not work anymore. This should be fixed in upcoming version v3.0.3 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11463

Comment: Thanks for your comment, hopefully this doesn't f up too many people in the meantime.

Comment: To make it work with Boostrap v3, replace $('.popover-link') by $("[data-toggle='popover']")...

Comment: @46enforce is that not just changing the selector? Would you not end up with the same object? My example implies that you add the class 'popover-link' to your popover links... But nice to see a solution that doesn't require this. Thanks.

Comment: OK I though that there was the .popover-link in Bootstrap 2 that's why. :) Indeed, my selector does the same thing than yours but it releases the need of using an extra class.

Comment: So the hidden-but-still-active-popover issue remains. Could be fixed with a little css, though: .popover.fade {z-index:-1} .popover.fade.in {z-index:99}.

Comment: @ravb79 what is the issue? Your comment seems out of place.

Comment: After activating the popover (and the subsequent hide action), the popover isn't completely hidden; it's just not visible. The issue is that content underneath the invisible yet present popover can't be clicked or hovered. Issue occurs on latest Chrome build, latest bootstrap 3 .js (could be other browsers as well, couldn't be bothered to check since this workaround should be required anyway)

Comment: Good update, but, it still won't work with popovers that were created from javascript. Check my answer for that solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19638199/275333

Comment: Just a comment to say it also works with bootstrap v2.3. I am talking about the last example: "One popover at a time please"

Comment: Instead of `'[data-toggle="popover"]'`, which doesn't work with JavaScript generated popovers, I used `'[data-original-title]'` as the selector.

Comment: Way to go! Great solution - separating out the logic and the content.

Comment: How to make the element exception? My popover can be closed by clicking anywhere outside the box. But, **I want the popover doesn't close when I click on the `<li>` element too**. mail me okierie@gmail.com @mattdlockyer

Comment: Does anyone know why this solution does not work with the latest version of bootstrap? The following is happening: Click button to show popover, then click body to dismiss popover, then click button to show popover and popover does not show. After it fails once if you click it again it shows. It is very strange.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, the fix for the glitch in the latest version of bootstrap 3.3.5 is here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/17702

Comment: @JTunney I'm running BS 3.3.6 and still seeing that behavior where it requires two clicks to open a popoever after dismissing one.

Comment: Workaround for the two clicks bug which still hasn't been fixed:
`$(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover').inState.click = false`

Comment: Unbelievable, I implemented your solution years ago but it doesn't work after updating. I cant believe I'm seeing your post again with updated solutions from time to time. I wish I could double up your answer. Looking forward to check out your solution when V4 is out.

Comment: @JTunney any solution for fixing this 'clicking twice' to enable popover?

Comment: The solution that works for me is the "Update: Bootstrap 3.3.6" (no double click outside needed, single popover at a time)
I'm, Using bootstrap 3.3.5  Thanks

Comment: In case of issue with `display: none` of popover (bootstrap 3.* issue on hide method), you need to add: `$(this).parent().find('.popover').remove();` after the `hide` call.

Comment: any solution for fixing this 'clicking twice' to enable popover?  it's 2021 and it still doesn't work

Comment: what about version 5 of bootstrap none of above solution worked for that

Comment: The edit on Feb 5, 2020 should have never been approved. The updated code is terrible and breaks this workaround.

Answer (score 87):

```
$('html').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).closest('.popover').length) {
        $('.popover').each(function(){
            $(this.previousSibling).popover('hide');
        });
    }
});
```

This closes all popovers if you click anywhere except on a popover

**UPDATE for Bootstrap 4.1**

```
$("html").on("mouseup", function (e) {
    var l = $(e.target);
    if (l[0].className.indexOf("popover") == -1) {
        $(".popover").each(function () {
            $(this).popover("hide");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I added a class to the button that triggers the popover (pop-btn) so it isn't included...  if(!$(e.target).closest('.popover').length && !$(e.target).closest('.btn').hasClass('pop-btn'))

Comment: with 3 popover buttons, this code make problems. in some case I can not click button and buttons are flashed.

Comment: Can't get this code to work... check this fiddle and please add a fiddle to your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/C5GBU/102/

Comment: Perfect for me. Other answers had side-effects when my "outside click" happened to open a new popover.

Comment: This works great, but needs to have a way to adapt this so that if you click on contents of the popover, it doesn't close. e.g. if you click on text inside a <b> tag inside the popover...

Comment: Supports clicks within child html tags:   // closes all popovers if you click anywhere except within a popover
$("html").on("mouseup", function (e) {
    var click_value = $(e.target)[0].className.indexOf("popover");
    var click_parent = $(e.target)[0].parentNode.className.indexOf("popover");
    if(click_value == -1 && click_parent != 0) {
        $(".popover").each(function () {
            $(this).popover("hide");
        });
    }
});

Answer (score 43):

**Most simple, most fail safe version**, works with any bootstrap version.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/guya/24mmM/

Demo 2: Not dismissing when clicking inside the popover content
http://jsfiddle.net/guya/fjZja/

Demo 3: Multiple popovers:
http://jsfiddle.net/guya/6YCjW/

---

Simply calling this line will dismiss all popovers:

```
$('[data-original-title]').popover('hide');
```

---

Dismiss all popovers when clicking outside with this code:

```
$('html').on('click', function(e) {
  if (typeof $(e.target).data('original-title') == 'undefined') {
    $('[data-original-title]').popover('hide');
  }
});
```

The snippet above attach a click event on the body.
When the user click on a popover, it'll behave as normal.
When the user click on something that is not a popover it'll close all popovers.

**It'll also work with popovers that are initiated with Javascript, as opposed to some other examples that will not work. (see the demo)**

If you don't want to dismiss when clicking inside the popover content, use this code (see link to 2nd demo):

```
$('html').on('click', function(e) {
  if (typeof $(e.target).data('original-title') == 'undefined' && !$(e.target).parents().is('.popover.in')) {
    $('[data-original-title]').popover('hide');
  }
});
```

Comment: Had a similar problem and this worked in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: If you bring the popovers closer such that the popovers overlap, when you hide a popover by clicking somewhere outside, one of the links stop working. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/qjcuyksb/1/

Comment: Thanx for the info Sandeep Girl, this was a generic bug in bootstrap 3.0.0 popover. It's fix when updating bootstrap. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/guya/awu1camL/

Comment: The last version doesn't work when using bootstrap-datepicker in the popover.

Comment: I liked this solution the best, because accepted answer started to be a bit of a resource hog with 30 or so popups

Comment: Perhaps `!$(e.target).closest('.popover.in').length` would be more efficient than `!$(e.target).parents().is('.popover.in')`.

Comment: I found `$('[data-original-title]').not(e.target).tooltip('hide');` to be best because you have to dismiss a tooltip/popover when another one is clicked.

Comment: bootstrap 5 updated their data attributes to include "bs" e.g. `data-bs-original-title`

Answer (score 22):

None of supposed high-voted solutions worked for me correctly.
Each leads to a bug when after opening and closing (by clicking on other elements) the popover for the first time, it doesn't open again, until you make **two** clicks on the triggering link instead of one.

So i modified it slightly:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var
        $popover,
        $target = $(e.target);

    //do nothing if there was a click on popover content
    if ($target.hasClass('popover') || $target.closest('.popover').length) {
        return;
    }

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        $popover = $(this);

        if (!$popover.is(e.target) &&
            $popover.has(e.target).length === 0 &&
            $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
        {
            $popover.popover('hide');
        } else {
            //fixes issue described above
            $popover.popover('toggle');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Nice, it is working for me. BTW you forgot a ); at the end of your code after last }

Comment: Had the same problem related to the second click. This should be the failsafe answer!

Comment: I also tried the previous solutions above, but as a guidance to those who are also looking for a solution as of 2016, this is a better solution.

Comment: top answer, works as advertised. as noted, others did not. this should be the top answer

Comment: Works perfectly except  I did not use data-toggel="popover". But you can specify any selector that matches your popover trigger elements. Nice solution and the only one that solved the two click issue for me.

Comment: This is prefect!

Answer (score 21):

With bootstrap 2.3.2 you can set the trigger to 'focus' and it just works:

```
$('#el').popover({trigger:'focus'});
```

Comment: +1, but important side note: This does not close the popover, if you click again on the button or anchor, while the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 18):

This is basically not very complex, but there is some checking to do to avoid glitches.

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/e6Gt8/)

```js
var $poped = $('someselector');

// Trigger for the popover
$poped.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.on('hover',function() {
            var popover = $this.data('popover');
            var shown = popover && popover.tip().is(':visible');
            if(shown) return;        // Avoids flashing
            $this.popover('show');
    });
});

// Trigger for the hiding
 $('html').on('click.popover.data-api',function() {
    $poped.popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: this dismisses the modal by clicking everywhere not outside

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a `popover()` on click rather than hover?

Comment: Of course, but you need to call `stopPropagation()` on the event passed to the click handler (if not, the _hiding_ handler immediately hide the popover). [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/e6Gt8/163/)

Comment: I've got the same functionality down below in far less code. This answer is bloated and a bit ridiculous for the question... All he wants is to close popovers when you click outside...  This is overkill and UGLY!

Comment: Correction, I believe I have BETTER functionality in FAR less code. It assumes you only want one popup at a time to be visible. If you like this please upvote my answer below: http://jsfiddle.net/P3qRK/1/ answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/14857326/1060487

Answer (score 11):

I made a jsfiddle to show you how to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/3yHTH/

The idea is to show the popover when you click the button and to hide the popover when you click outside the button.

## HTML

```
<a id="button" href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Click for popover</a>
```

## JS

```
$('#button').popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    position: 'bottom',
    title: 'Example',
    content: 'Popover example for SO'
}).click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(this).popover('show');
});

$('html').click(function() {
    $('#button').popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: nice demo. I am wondering how you could call popover on the Jquery object, popover is a bootstrap js plugin, but you don't include any bootstrap js file there?

Comment: There is a js file in the jsfiddle. Look at the left column -> Manage resources.

Comment: Ok, I see there is a bootstrap js. but it is not checked, it still works?

Comment: Yes, it works. Anyway, I searched in google: `jsfiddle bootstrap` and it gave me the skeleton of bootstrap css+js in jsfiddle.

Comment: My only problem with this is that you hide the popover when you click it. Might as well just use a tooltip.

Comment: @NoBrainer Use [matt's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14857326/1004046) instead of my solution then =)

Comment: I like this solution as this seems to use less resource to loop through than matt's solution

Answer (score 9):

simply add this attribute with the element

```
data-trigger="focus"
```

Comment: Initially this didn't work for me with Bootstrap 3.3.7 but then I read the docs and they have some guidance that's worth a mention here. From the Dismissible popover example in the docs "For proper cross-browser and cross-platform behavior, you must use the <a> tag, not the <button> tag, and you also must include the role="button" and tabindex attributes."

Comment: data-bs-trigger="focus"  for bootstrap 5

Answer (score 7):

**Just add this attribute to html element to close popover in next click.**

```
data-trigger="focus"
```

reference from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click

Comment: This is actually a really great solution. I tried all the other answers and nothing worked, besides they are all complicated and brittle. This solution works for me in Bootstrap 4 and it is simple, elegant and robust. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap 5 UPDATE:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var
        $popover,
        $target = $(e.target);

    //do nothing if there was a click on popover content
    if ($target.hasClass('popover') || $target.closest('.popover').length) {
        return;
    }

    $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        $popover = $(this);

        if (!$popover.is(e.target) &&
            $popover.has(e.target).length === 0 &&
            $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
        {
            $popover.popover('hide');
        } 
    });
})
```

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: This is working as expected for me. Multiple open/close cycles are fine. Clicking content doesn't close. Clicking on a different popover closes the first, but correctly opens the second.

Answer (score 5):

According to http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers,

```
<button type="button" class="popover-dismiss" data-toggle="popover" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="Popover Content">Dismissible popover</button>
```

Use the focus trigger to dismiss popovers on the next click that the user makes.

```
$('.popover-dismiss').popover({
    trigger: 'focus'
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac browsers that follow OS X native behaviour (that doesn't focus nor blur buttons on click). These include Firefox and Safari. Bootstrap guys made a big mistake here, as these popovers can't even be opened, let alone dismissed.

Comment: @AnteVrli Maybe this was not yet in the documentation when you wrote your comment but now the docs say: "For proper cross-browser and cross-platform behavior, you must use the `<a>` tag, not the `<button>` tag, and you also must include the `role="button"` and `tabindex` attributes." Did you try it with these specifications?

Comment: Well, there *is* a problem with this answer, which has nothing to do with platform compatibility: pressing a mouse button *inside* a popover will dismiss the popover because the element that triggers the popover will lose focus. Forget having users be able to copy-and-paste from popovers: as soon as the mouse button is down, the popover closes. If you have actionable items in the popover (buttons, links), users won't be able to use them.

Comment: So much for 'cross-platform' because in bootstrap 4.0.0-beta and 4.0.0-beta.2 I cannot get this to work on Mac in Chrome :(

Answer (score 4):

This solution works fine :

```
$("body")   .on('click'     ,'[data-toggle="popover"]', function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("body")   .on('click'     ,'.popover' , function(e) { 
     e.stopPropagation();
});

$("body")   .on('click'  , function(e) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: This worked, though only needed the last two of the three

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a solution that works with Bootstrap 5 and no jQuery, even when the popovers are dynamically generated (ie manually triggered):

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var in_popover = e.target.closest(".popover");

    if (!in_popover) {
        var popovers = document.querySelectorAll('.popover.show');

        if (popovers[0]) {
            var triggler_selector = `[aria-describedby=${popovers[0].id}]`;

            if (!e.target.closest(triggler_selector)) {
                let the_trigger = document.querySelector(triggler_selector);
                if (the_trigger) {
                    bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(the_trigger).hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947749/how-can-i-close-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-with-a-click-from-anywhere-else-on). The same answer I gave then still applies:

I had a similar need, and found this [great little extension of the Twitter Bootstrap Popover by Lee Carmichael, called BootstrapX - clickover](http://blog.leecarmichael.com/2012/04/bootstrapx-clickover.html). He also has some usage examples [here](http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html). Basically it will change the popover into an interactive component which will close when you click elsewhere on the page, or on a close button within the popover. This will also allow multiple popovers open at once and a bunch of other nice features.

Answer (score 3):

This is late to the party... but I thought I'd share it.
I love the popover but it has so little built-in functionality. I wrote a bootstrap extension .bubble() that is everything I'd like popover to be. Four ways to dismiss. Click outside, toggle on the link, click the X, and hit escape.

It positions automatically so it never goes off the page.

https://github.com/Itumac/bootstrap-bubble

This is  not a  gratuitous self promo...I've grabbed other people's code so many times in my life, I wanted to offer my own efforts. Give it a whirl and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Modified accepted solution. What I've experienced was that after some popovers were hidden, they would have to be clicked twice to show up again. Here's what I did to ensure that popover('hide') wasn't being called on already hidden popovers.

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-original-title]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            var popoverElement = $(this).data('bs.popover').tip();
            var popoverWasVisible = popoverElement.is(':visible');

            if (popoverWasVisible) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
                $(this).click(); // double clicking required to reshow the popover if it was open, so perform one click now
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("#menu").click(function(){ return false; });
jQuery(document).one("click", function() { jQuery("#menu").fadeOut(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use event bubbling to remove the popup from the DOM. It is a bit dirty, but works fine.

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', '.popover-close', function(e) {
  return $(this).parents('.popover').remove();
});
```

In your html add the .popover-close class to the content inside the popover that should close the popover.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the 'hide' method does not work if you create the popover with selector delegation, instead 'destroy' must be used.

I made it work like that:

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]'
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('destroy');
        }
    });
});
```

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vdimchev/anhLtjdp/)

Answer (score 2):

We found out we had an issue with the solution from @mattdlockyer (thanks for the solution!). When using the selector property for the popover constructor like this...

```
$(document.body').popover({selector: '[data-toggle=popover]'});
```

...the proposed solution for BS3 won't work. Instead it creates a second popover instance local to its `$(this)`. Here is our solution to prevent that:

```
$(document.body).on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            var bsPopover = $(this).data('bs.popover'); // Here's where the magic happens
            if (bsPopover) bsPopover.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

As mentioned the `$(this).popover('hide');` will create a second instance due to the delegated listener. The solution provided only hides popovers which are already instanciated.

I hope I could save you guys some time.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap [natively supports this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers):

[JS Bin Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/qetuki)

> **Specific markup required for dismiss-on-next-click**
>
> For proper cross-browser and cross-platform behavior, you must use the `<a>` tag, *not* the `<button>` tag, and you also must include the `role="button"` and `tabindex` attributes.

Comment: In bootstrap 4.0.0-beta and 4.0.0-beta.2 I cannot get this to work on Mac in Chrome :(

Comment: Clicking anywhere closes this popover, the questioner requires "click outside the popover closes it", which is different.

Answer (score 2):

this solution gets rid of the pesky 2nd click when showing the popover for the second time

tested with with Bootstrap v3.3.7

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.popover').each(function () {
        var popover = $(this).data('bs.popover');
        if (!popover.$element.is(e.target)) {
            popover.inState.click = false;
            popover.hide();                
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried many of the previous answers, really nothing works for me but this solution did:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click

> They recommend to use anchor tag not button and take care of role="button" + data-trigger="focus" + tabindex="0" attributes.

Ex:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" 
data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="amazing content">
Dismissible popover</a>
```

Comment: try this reference too :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466903/bootstrap-popover-hide-on-click-outside

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:
My scenario included more popovers on the same page, and hiding them just made them invisible and because of that, clicking on items behind the popover was not possible.
The idea is to mark the specific popover-link as 'active' and then you can simply 'toggle' the active popover. Doing so will close the popover completely
    $('.popover-link').popover({ html : true, container: 'body' })

```
$('.popover-link').popover().on 'shown.bs.popover', ->
  $(this).addClass('toggled')

$('.popover-link').popover().on 'hidden.bs.popover', ->
  $(this).removeClass('toggled')

$("body").on "click", (e) ->
  $openedPopoverLink = $(".popover-link.toggled")
  if $openedPopoverLink.has(e.target).length == 0
    $openedPopoverLink.popover "toggle"
    $openedPopoverLink.removeClass "toggled"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just remove other active popovers before the new popover is shown (bootstrap 3):

```
$(".my-popover").popover();

$(".my-popover").on('show.bs.popover',function () {
    $('.popover.in').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @guya works, unless you have something like a datepicker or timepicker in the popover. To fix that, this is what I have done.

```
if (typeof $(e.target).data('original-title') === 'undefined' && 
    !$(e.target).parents().is('.popover.in')) {
        var x = $(this).parents().context;
        if(!$(x).hasClass("datepicker") && !$(x).hasClass("ui-timepicker-wrapper")){
            $('[data-original-title]').popover('hide');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tested with 3.3.6 and second click is ok

```
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
            .click(function () {
            $(this).popover('toggle');
        });;

        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
                //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
                //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
                if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nessajtr/yxpM5/1/

```
var clickOver = clickOver || {};
clickOver.uniqueId = $.now();

clickOver.ClickOver = function (selector, options) {
    var self = this;

    //default values
    var isVisible, clickedAway = false;

    var callbackMethod = options.content;
var uniqueDiv = document.createElement("div");
var divId = uniqueDiv.id = ++clickOver.uniqueId;
uniqueDiv.innerHTML = options.loadingContent();

options.trigger = 'manual';
options.animation = false;
options.content = uniqueDiv;

self.onClose = function () {
    $("#" + divId).html(options.loadingContent());
    $(selector).popover('hide')
    isVisible = clickedAway = false;
};
self.onCallback = function (result) {
    $("#" + divId).html(result);
};

$(selector).popover(options);

//events
$(selector).bind("click", function (e) {
    $(selector).filter(function (f) {
        return $(selector)[f] != e.target;
    }).popover('hide');

    $(selector).popover("show");
    callbackMethod(self.onCallback);

    isVisible = !(clickedAway = false);
});

$(document).bind("click", function (e) {
    if (isVisible && clickedAway && $(e.target).parents(".popover").length == 0) {
        self.onClose();
        isVisible = clickedAway = false;
    } else clickedAway = true;
});
```

}

this is my solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

This approach ensures that you can close a popover by clicking anywhere on the page. If you click on another clickable entity, it hides all other popovers. The animation:false is required else you will get a jquery .remove error in your console.

```
$('.clickable').popover({
 trigger: 'manual',
 animation: false
 }).click (evt) ->
  $('.clickable').popover('hide')
  evt.stopPropagation()
  $(this).popover('show')

$('html').on 'click', (evt) ->
  $('.clickable').popover('hide')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my first attempt at actually answering something on stackoverflow so here goes nothing :P

It appears that it isn't quite clear that this functionality actually works out of the box on the latest bootstrap (well, if you're willing to compromise *where* the user can click. I'm not sure if you have to put 'click hover' per-se but on an iPad, click works as a toggle.

The end result is, on a desktop you can hover or click (most users will hover). On a touch device, touching the element will bring it up, and touching it again will take it down. Of course, this is a slight compromise from your original requirement but at least your code is now cleaner :)

> $(".my-popover").popover({
>       trigger: 'click hover'
>   });

Answer (score 0):

Taking Matt Lockyer's code, I've done a simple reset so the dom doesn't get covered by the element on hide.

Matt's code: http://mattlockyer.com/2013/04/08/close-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-when-clicking-outside/

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrsmith/Wd2qS/

```
    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
    //hide popover from dom to prevent covering elements
    $('.popover').css('display', 'none');
    //bring popover back if trigger element is clicked
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $('.popover').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
    //hide popover with .popover method
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will hide by clicking outside.

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
    //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
    //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $(this).popover('hide');
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with mattdlockyer's solution because I was setting up popover links dynamically using code like this:

```
$('body').popover({
        selector : '[rel="popover"]'
});
```

So I had to modify it like so. It fixed a lot of issues for me:

```
$('html').on('click', function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
    //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
    //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $(this).popover('destroy');
    }
  });
});
```

Remember that destroy gets rid of the element, so the selector part is important on initializing the popovers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html').on('click.popover', function (e) {
    var allpopins = $('.popover.in');
    if (allpopins.has(e.target).length > 0 &&
        !$('.btn', allpopins).is(e.target))
        return;
    // recognise pop-up 
    var id = $(e.target).attr('aria-describedby');
    var popin = $("#" + id);
    //on any button click in entire pop-up hide this pop-ups
    $(popin).on(".btn", function () { popin.remove(); });
    // on any place out of entire popup hide all pop-ups 
    $('.popover.in').not(popin).remove();
});
```

This is my the best performance solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer works very well, just to add a angular directive in case you are using angular like me:

```
app.directive('popover', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
            });

            elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                $('#notification').popover('toggle');
            })

            $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
                //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
                if (!elem.is(e.target)
                    && elem.has(e.target).length === 0
                    && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    elem.popover('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The html code:

```
<a popover tabindex="0" role="button"
   id="notification"
   data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual"
   data-container="body" data-placement="bottom"
   data-content="This is a popover">
   Popover button
</a>
```

It should have been as simple as use `data-trigger='click focus'`, because according to bootstrap:

> How popover is triggered - click | hover | focus | manual. You may pass multiple triggers; separate them with a space. manual cannot be combined with any other trigger.

However, use click and focus together doesn't work for me for unknown reason, instead I have to toggle it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover').inState.click = false
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Please add more information/description on how this work and solve the question, so that others can understand it easily without asking for more detail. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the latest update of the accepted answer:
If you have some tooltips enabled and you open a popover and then click on a tooltip-having element, the text of the tooltip will be displayed as a popover to.

To prevent this, just add

```
 if ($(this).data('bs.popover')) {
```

inside the if-statement (or add it concatenated with && to the if-statement)

```
// only show one popover at the time and hide on clicking outside
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"],[data-original-title]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            if ($(this).data('bs.popover')) {
                (($(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover') || {}).inState || {}).click = false  // fix for BS 3.3.6
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good and simple solution to this problem. 
Doing it this way, we only have an event listener activated when it needs to be. 
Furthermore we don't have a problem with the popover not appearing because an
event disarming the popup is firing at the same time.

Add the popover to the HTML

```
   <input id="popoverId" type="text" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Popover content">
```

Show the popover when you want.

```
$('#popoverId').popover('show');
```

Add this listener to your Javascript. This listener will fire as soon as the popover is shown 
and will attach a listener to the body which will hide the 
popover when the user clicks anywhere on the body of the page and then remove the event listener until the popover will be shown again.

```
$('#popoverId').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $('body').click(function () {
        $('#popoverId').popover('hide');
        $('body').off();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to highest two answers, I have a little fix:

```html
<span class="btn btn-info btn-minier popover-info" data-rel="popover"
                                              data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title=""
                                              data-content="popover-content"
                                              data-original-title="popover-title">
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-info smaller-100"></i>
                                        </span>
```

```js
            $('[data-rel=popover]').popover({html: true});
            $(document).on("shown.bs.popover", '[data-rel=popover]', function () {
                $('[data-rel="popover"][popover-show="1"]').popover('hide');
                $(this).attr('popover-show', '1');
            });
            $(document).on("hidden.bs.popover", '[data-rel=popover]', function () {
                if ($(this).attr('popover-show') === '0') {
                    // My important fix: using bootstrap 3.4.1, if hide popover by .popover('hide') and click to show, popover internal treat it is already shown and dispatch hidden event immediately without popover anything.
                    $(this).popover('toggle');
                } else {
                    $(this).attr('popover-show', '0');
                }
            });
            $('html').on('click', function (e) {
                if (typeof $(e.target).data('original-title') == 'undefined'
                    && typeof $(e.target).parent().data('original-title') == 'undefined'
                    && !$(e.target).parents().is('.popover.in')) {
                    $('[data-rel="popover"][popover-show="1"]').popover('hide');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Breakdown:

First, add a `click` event listener to the `body`.

On Click, check whether or not there's an element with a `popover` class (Bootstrap removes the popover element from the `DOM` on dismissal).

If the `.popover` element exists, check the `event.target` which will tell you where the User clicked on the page. If it's part of the `.popover` element, do nothing. If not, `hide` the popover ([docs here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/#popoverhide)).

NOTE: The `aria-describedby` condition prevents the popover from being hidden when it is initially fired/shown.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  let isPopoverShown = Boolean(document.querySelector('.popover'));
  let isClickNotPopover = !event.target.closest('.popover');

  if (
        isPopoverShown 
     && isClickNotPopover 
     && !event.target?.getAttribute('aria-describedby')?.startsWith('popover')
  ) {
     $('.popover').popover('hide')
  }

})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("body").find('.popover').removeClass('in');
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer add some commentary to this line? What it does, how it works, how it differs from other solutions, whether there are any caveats... Thank you!