# How can I tell if an event is being fired by the same event that created it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following events:

```
$(button).on('mouseup', function (event1) {
    $(something).show();

    $(document).on('mouseup', function (event2) {
        $(something).hide();
    });

});
```

So, it shows "something" when button is clicked and hides it when the document is clicked. How can I make sure the second evnet doesn't trigger in the same event that created it? right now the something will show and hide instantly (at least on firefox).

I need to do this without any globals of any kind, preferably.

Comment: Setting an event handler from within an event handler is almost always wrong (as it is here). Instead of focusing on the mechanics, describe your goal.

Comment: This adds new mouseup event to the document, every time a button is released? Apart from that, did you try with `console.log(event1)` and `console.log(event2)` and see what that gets you? Event has `target` attribute in jQuery, you could use that. Still, you need to fix your code.

Comment: @D.Kasipovic it's strange. I tried comparing timestamps and if i simply log the events, it shows them alright, but if I use them in an if, statement, it shows them as undefined. I'll change the question to show how;

Comment: @D.Kasipovic nevermind, i'm a moron. I used event.timestamp instead of event.timeStamp. It works now. I don't know if to change the question to include the answer or just answer it myself....

Comment: I agree with @Jon here, you are almost certainly doing this wrong. But at the very least, you should probably replace `.on` with `.one` so that your nested event will only fire once and then be removed. Otherwise you will pile up `.mouseup` event handlers until your web page grinds to a halt.

Comment: @MattBurland thanks for your answer. I didn't use .one because in my actual working code I remove all the events in a namespace, including the current one. Also I'm aware it's not usually good form to create events inside of other events but I can't avoid it here.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$(button).on('mouseup', function (event1) {
    $(something).show();
    event1.stopPropagation();
    $(document).one('mouseup', function (event2) {
        $(something).hide();
    });

});
```

`stopPropagation()` will stop the event from going past the button (to the document).

`one()` will only run the event once and then go away... can be recreated again with another click on the button.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7Yrr/)

Comment: stopPropagation will allow multiple somethings to be shown if I have multiple buttons. It's a solution but Matt's is better

Comment: @Bogdan, you didn't mention that, however I'm not sure how Matt's would do any different... except with his, a click on the button would also hide. If you want the best solution you should show your dom (or a sample of it). Also, `show()` just shows... it wont create multiple so I'm not sure what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/v7Yrr/1/

Comment: Yeah sorry I was thinking ahead of myself. This was just an example, my code is way more complicated and the show() and hide() functions are replaced by callbacks passed to my component

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that doesn't rely on timestamps:

```
$("button").on('mouseup', function (event1) {
    $("#something").show();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(document).one('mouseup', function (event2) {
             $("#something").hide();
        });
    }, 0);

});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3y75x/)

Using `setTimeout` with a delay of 0 will make it execute the code as soon as it's finished with this event. Also note I'm using `one` rather than `on` because you only need this event handler one time and without it you will end up attaching unlimited numbers of event handlers, every single one of which will need processing when a `mouseup` fires anywhere on your page.

A less silly solution might look like this:

```
$("button").on('mouseup', function (event1) {
     $("#something").show();
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function (event2) {
    if(event2.target != $("button")[0]) {
        $("#something").hide();
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3y75x/1/)

Comment: I'll accept this answer even tho I used mine. This answer is more to the point.

Comment: The less silly solution is not functionally the same as the first. Also it doesn't answer the specific question. Thanks for the first one tho, didn't think about using timeout.

Comment: @Bogdan: *Functionally* it is the same. It achieves the same goal of having something appear when you click the button and disappear when you click anywhere else. It functions the same way. The only *technical* difference is that the second solution always attaches the `mouseup` handler to document where the first only attaches a handler if somebody clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you isolate the event like so:

```
$(button).on('mouseup', function (event1) {
    $(something).show();
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function (event2) {
        $(something).hide();
});
```

Comment: Even so, it isn't ok to place a 'mouseup' event on the whole document. It could override your button event

Comment: It's not usually okay but I'm building a popup/popover component and I need a way to close the popover when the user clicks anywhere on the document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205921/popover-close-pop-over-when-clicked-outside-of-pop-over Check out this solution it seems more elegant

Comment: Yes it's more elegant but it's also not useful to me. I'm building this for a very broad deffinition of what a popup/popover is. I'm leaving it to the user of the component to declare the show/hide functions and show/hide conditions. That's why I need this "ugly" event structure.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the event.timeStamp property to check if the two events are distinct. Also added an unbind and a namespace to the document event to prevent event stacking.

```
$(button).on('mouseup', function (event1) {
    $(something).show();

    $(document).on('mouseup.'+someIdentifier, function (event2) {
        if(event1.timeStamp != event2.timeStamp) {
            $(something).hide();
            $(document).unbind('mouseup.'+someIdentifier);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Too complicated for just hiding and showing element.

Comment: It's not just for hiding or showing an element. The question is about differentiating the two events, and I think that for a click event, the timestamp is a pretty good differentiator.