# Arshaw fullcalendar & twitter bootstrap Popover (How to dismiss a popover by clicking outside?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, popover

I've found the following example which shows the behavior I require from popover:
[How to dismiss a Twitter Bootstrap popover by clicking outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703093/how-to-dismiss-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-by-clicking-outside/14857326#14857326)

However, does anyone know how to achieve similar behavior inside fullcalendar?
(i.e. with fullcalendar events)  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Actually I think I found a solution for my problem:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            if (!event.url)
            {
                element.popover({
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    html:true,                        
                    title: 'text',
                    content: 'text                                
                });

                $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                    if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
                        element.popover('hide');
                });
            }           
        }         

});
```

This seems to work well inside fullcalendar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler: you can attach the hide event to the actual element itself:

```
element.on('click', function() {
  element.popover('hide');
};
```