# Bootstrap popover, hide on click outside?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

using bootstrap popover, and now  im trying to get this code to click outside the popover to close the popover:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

But when i use this part, i can close the popover but i cant click the other buttons, anyone got any idea how i can do that?

All the buttons:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="popover">This opens popover</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Other link</a> <- Doesn't work 
<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Other link</a> <- Doesn't work
```

Comment: better check your `z-index` i think something is overcome to popupbox

Comment: @RahilWazir That helped a little bit, the popover has the class .fade and fade in, and .fade has opacity:0 so it is still there but still not^^ Now i need to find out how to remove the opacity from there, because when i do that the code i have for closing it wont work

Comment: make a fiddle it'll be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean with **Doesn't work** ? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found this : http://bootply.com/99372

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function () {
        // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

It's almost the same code as you...

Comment: Problem with this, is for some reason, the manually called popover('hide') doesnt remove it from the dom so the popover div remains and covers anything under it.

Comment: Could you explain your problem or create a fiddle ?

Comment: Bootstrap made a release that fixed my problem so your solution now works as you described.  Prior to that, the popover would maintain itself in the dom.  It would be invisible but still hold its HxW thus making any elements below it's z-index unclickable.

Comment: Works for tooltip too, just change all `popover` strings for `tooltip`

Comment: I would recommend using the "mousedown" event instead of the "click". This way popover will be also hidden during long selections or drag'n'drops.

Comment: This is great because it closes any open popovers before opening another one. Multiple popovers open at once is annoying and the more that are open the higher chance they cover up the element you need to click to close them. Since there is no close button this should be the default behavior. It also helps panicking users that just start clicking everywhere to get the obtrusive, unintuitive popover to close.

Answer (score 14):

Just add this element to close the popover on next click.

```
data-trigger="focus"
```

Reference from here:
[Bootstrap Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers)

Comment: Anyone care to explain why this answer is downvoted? It seems like the perfect answer to me. It's short, specific and correct, and even references the official documentation. I don't get it.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted it, but the reason is probably that it's not what the guy asked. He (and I) want the popover to disappear only when clicking OUTSIDE of it. data-trigger="focus" hides it also when clicking inside.

Comment: @Asaf no it's not... I want to close in both inside and outside click, but only working when i am clicking outside.. how can i archive both. By inside , i meant the `ICON` which on click lead to appear popover. yea it do dispear on click inside popover body thou.

Answer (score 8):

In fact, you don't even need JS, since there's already a setting for this in Bootstrap.

See : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click

"Specific markup required for dismiss-on-next-click
For proper cross-browser and cross-platform behavior, you must use the `<a>` tag, not the `<button>` tag, and you also must include the role="button" and tabindex attributes."

Ex. :

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

Comment: It's always helpful if you include the relevant (code) parts from the external resource, instead of just linking to it.

Comment: Though it's not the most complete answer, this is the correct way to do it. However, this does not work if you choose to put any interactive content inside because all clicks will close the popover.

Comment: In needs data-trigger="focus" otherwise it does not work. Example: <a tabindex="0" role="button" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-content="Text"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i></a>

Comment: Thank you your solution is working. Bootstrap provide default setting for it.

Comment: This closes the popover on second click, not on outside click. This closes even If i click inside the popover

Comment: Thank you, this is currently the correct way which I'm looking for

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#dismiss-on-next-click

Answer (score 6):

Try this. It will close the popover when clicking the outside of the popover.

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
//did not click a popover toggle, or icon in popover toggle, or popover
if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover' && $(e.target).parents('[data-toggle="popover"]').length === 0
    && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) {
    (($('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide').data('bs.popover') || {}).inState || {}).click = false;
}
});
```

Another solution,

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

add **tabindex="0"** and **data-trigger="focus"**

Answer (score 4):

Just hiding popover won't work. You will need to click twice to show popover again.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16732

To make it work correctly for Bootstrap 3.3.6. Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                (($(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover')||{}).inState||{}).click = false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Bootstrap 4 uses `_activeTrigger` instead of `inState`:

```
$(e.target).data("bs.popover")._activeTrigger.click = false
```

Comment: What is 'inState' here?

Comment: inState tells the current state of the popover.
Here we are resetting the popover click state using 'inState.click=false'
which would have been otherwise 'true' as we are using the click event to show this popover. 
    'inState.hover'
    'inState.focus'
are some options available.

Comment: Please up-vote if you found this useful. Vivekraj K R

Answer (score 2):

I just code my own variant of your answer, because I got an issue where if I try to reopen a popover after an ousite click, I needed to click the button 2 times.

The goal of this code is the simulate a click on the button which activate the popover.

So there is the code :

```
$('html').on('click', function(e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function() { //Loop for everything containing a data-toggle="popover"
        if ($(this).attr('aria-describedby') != null ) { //Check if the popover is active / contain an aria-describedby with a value
            var id = $(this).attr('aria-describedby'); //Put the value in a variable
            if (!$(e.target).closest(".popover-content").length && $(e.target).attr("aria-describedby") != id && !$(e.target).closest('[aria-describedby="'+id+'"').length) { //Look if the click is a child of the popover box or if it's the button itself or a child of the button
                $('[aria-describedby="'+id+'"]').trigger( "click" ); //trigger a click as if you clicked the button
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution will work almost anytime. I think a stoppropagation can't block it. The problem is, for each click you do, this function will loop for every popover. Other solution can be better, like the build-in one. In some case, you can have problem with them, so this code will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Even i had that problem.. and i am able to get rid off it..

just add this line in your code.. :

```js
 $(this).css('display', 'none');
```

i.e

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
          $('[data-toggle="popover"]').css('display','none');
        }
    });
});
```

**Suggestion:** Instead of **'body'** tag you can use **'document'**

Answer (score 0):

actually I'm fine with this code because none of the solution above worked for me:

```
 $('body').on('mouseleave', '.popover', function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Comment: yeah it works. but when you try to click the POP OVER again. it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this**,below code is work for me,
Put below code in js file

$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
$('html').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
           if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});

and HTML tag should be like this

<a data-toggle="popover"   data-placement="bottom" data-content-id="notifications-content">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap cannot reach indepentently popover id's. We have to read aria-describedby attribute related with the element.

Code below is removes popover:

```
$("#"+$(relatedElementId).attr("aria-describedby")).remove();
```

relatedElementId: popover's associated element