# angular-ui-bootstrap : Handling click event on popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using `ui bootstrap` for showing popover on some link. I need to handle click event on popover. I searched for handling click event on popover but didn't get how to register and then handle click event on it.

Here my code below:

```
a#notification(href='', popover='You got a new notification!!!', popover-placement='left', ng-click='onClickNotification()')
    img.icon-notification(src='../images/speaker.png')
```

Is there some other way to register a click event listener on it?

Thanks

Comment: [Check this example, it might help!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770019/angular-ui-bootstrap-popover-how-add-a-close-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listenet like this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp