# Angular UI Bootstrap Popover - How close all opened popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I've a table with a popover for every cell as in the follow example:

the call to popover:

```
<td ng-repeat="i in c.installments" ng-class="{ 'first' : i.first, 'last' : i.last, 'advance' : i.advance.value > 0, 'edited' : i.edited, 'final-installment' : i.last }" popover-trigger="{{ popoverFilter(i) }}" popover-placement="top" popover-title="{{i.id == 0 ? 'Advance' : 'Installment ' + i.id}}" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-template="popoverTemplate(i)" ng-init="payment= i; newpayment= i.amount.rounded_value" >
```

The popover template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="editPopoverTemplate.html">
    <form name="editPayment">
      <h2>{{payment.amount.value|currency:undefined:cents}}</h2>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : editPayment.newpayment.$invalid }">
        <label>New value:</label>
        <input type="number" name="newpayment" ng-model="newpayment" class="form-control no-spinner" step="1" min="10" required>
        <span ng-messages="editPayment.newpayment.$error" class="help-block" role="alert">
          <span ng-message="required">The value is mandatory</span>
          <span ng-message="min">The value is too low</span>
          <span ng-message="max">The value is too hight</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button class="btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-disabled="editPayment.$invalid">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </script>
```

[working example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ArIDkkXs9Ev6ROBLSvDd?p=preview)

I need to close all opened popover when new popover is open.
I need only a popover open.
It's possible? I need to extend the Angular UI Bootstrap library to do that?

Any help is appreciated.

The solution suggested in the linked answer below allow two popover open but i need to have only one popover opened, when a popover is open the other (opened) must be closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide Angular UI Bootstrap popover when clicking outside of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512748/hide-angular-ui-bootstrap-popover-when-clicking-outside-of-it)

Comment: The solution suggested in the linked answer allow two popover open but i need to have only one popover opened, when a popover is open the other )opened) must be closed

Comment: The code in that question tells you how to close the popover when clicking on something outside it. You can use the same solution in your case too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in release 0.13.4, we've added the ability to programmatically open and close a tooltip and popover via the `tooltip-is-open` or `popover-is-open` boolean property.  Via this, you can easily open and close your tooltips and popover on demand.

Comment: good news, a question, i see that the stable version available on bower or via download is in this moment the 0.13.3.
When version 0.13.4 will be released as stable?

Comment: right now, the plan is to release this thursday, 03SEP2015.