# How to close Angular-bootstrap popover when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am attempting to close my Angular-bootstrap `popover`s when clicking anywhere outside the popovers. According to an answer to this question this can now be accomplished (in version 0.13.4) by utilizing the new `popover-is-open` attribute: [Hide Angular UI Bootstrap popover when clicking outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512748/hide-angular-ui-bootstrap-popover-when-clicking-outside-of-it)

Currently my HTML looks like so:

```
<div
  ng-click="level.openTogglePopover()"
  popover-template="level.changeLevelTemplate"
  popover-trigger="none"
  popover-placement="right"
  popover-is-open="level.togglePopover">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

...and my relevant controller code:

```
vm.togglePopover = false;

vm.openTogglePopover = function() {
  vm.togglePopover = !vm.togglePopover;
};
```

This works great for opening/closing the popover when clicking on the button referenced above. My question is, how would I extend this functionality to close the popover when clicking anywhere outside of the popover? How would I set up my event handling to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) we could play with?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, if you want the popover to close on **any** click, not only the one outside of your popover, you can do it using existing UI-Bootstrap code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button"
        popover-template="level.changeLevelTemplate"
        popover-trigger="focus"
        popover-placement="right">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
</button>
```

The trick here is to drop the surrounding `<div>` and put the `popover-trigger="focus"` right on the button.

---

If you need to actually close the popover only for clicks outside the popover content, then it will be more difficult. You need a new directive, like this one:

```
app.directive('clickOutside', function ($parse, $timeout) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      function handler(event) {
        if(!$(event.target).closest(element).length) {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            $parse(attrs.clickOutside)(scope);
          });
        }
      }

      $timeout(function () {
        // Timeout is to prevent the click handler from immediately
        // firing upon opening the popover.
        $(document).on("click", handler);
      });
      scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
        $(document).off("click", handler);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then, in your popover template, use the directive on the outermost element:

```
<div click-outside="level.closePopover()">
   ... (actual popover content goes here)
</div>
```

Finally, in your controller, implement the `closePopover` function:

```
vm.closePopover = function () {
  vm.togglePopover = false;
};
```

What we've done here is:

- we're listening on any clicks on the document, and, if the click is outside of the element to which we added our `close-popover` directive:

  - we invoke whatever code was the value of `close-popover`
- we also clean up after ourselves when the directive's scope is destroyed (i.e. when the popover is closed) so that we don't handle the clicks anymore.

It's not the cleanest solution, as you have to invoke the controller method from within the popover template, but it's the best I came up with.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm very close now, but my popover closes when I click inside it still. This is because I'm not using jQuery so I need to tweak some of the link function code. Any idea how this line could be written without using jQuery: `if(!$(event.target).closest(element).length)`?

Comment: I think you can emulate this by e.g. if (!element.contains(event.target)) {...

Comment: That's what I've tried, but I'm getting an `element.contains is not a function` error.

Comment: Strange, element should always be a Node... Can you debug and check what type it is exactly?

Comment: Ended up checking to see if the element contains the HTML of the target: `if (element.context.outerHTML.indexOf($event.target.outerHTML) === -1)`.

Comment: Don't do that, it's very ineffective. I just remembered: element is a jqLite instance, you need to call element[0] to get the DOM element. So your if statement would be: if (!element[0].contains(event.target)) {...

Answer (score 13):

Since angular-ui 1.0.0, there is a new `outsideClick` trigger for tooltips and popovers (introduced in [this pull request](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/4419):

```html
<div
  uib-popover-template="level.changeLevelTemplate"
  popover-trigger="outsideClick"
  popover-placement="right">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: superb. popover-trigger is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want the popover to close when a user clicks pretty much anywhere except on the inside of the popover itself, barring the actual close button. This could be accomplished with an event listener:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    if(!$(event.target).is('#foo')) {
        // Code to hide/remove popovers
    }
});
```

Check out this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jz6gwQstuPvIvtT1cckE?p=preview).

Or, in your specific scenario:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    if(!$(event.target).is('.my-popover-class')) {
        vm.togglePopover = false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to do the event handling yourself as when you use the new `*-is-open` attributes, there is no event handling.

If you don't need the programmatic control over opening/closing the popover, then you can use the built in `focus` trigger to give you what you want.

Comment: I've changed my trigger to `popover-trigger="focus"`, but the popovers do not even open now.

Answer (score 1):

> close the popover when clicking anywhere outside of the popover

Some time ago I've found this answer useful: [How to dismiss a Twitter Bootstrap popover by clicking outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703093/how-to-dismiss-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-by-clicking-outside/14857326#14857326)

Code I used in one of my demos *(mixing `angular` and `jQuery`event handling which is probably not recommended)* is specific to my needs but may give some idea:

```
  app.directive("eventlistener", function($rootScope) {
    $(window).resize($rootScope.closeAllPopovers); // because Bootstrap popovers don't look good when misplaced

    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $('body').on('mouseup touchend', $rootScope.closeAllPopovers);
      }
    };
  });

  $rootScope.closeAllPopovers = function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
      if (e) {
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
          $(this).popover('hide');
        }
      } else {
        // No event passed - closing all popovers programmatically
        $(this).popover('hide');
      }
    });
  };
```

I'd also suggest looking at the difference between:

- https://api.jquery.com/is/
- https://api.jquery.com/has/