# How to hide uib-popover on click outside of the popover in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<button class="btn btn-default blue btn-lg h-ask btn-block" popover-placement="bottom" uib-popover-template="popover_home.templateUrl">ASK</button>
```

The above is the code for angular js popover, in the html template of the Popover two input fields also there , so when user submits the html form inside popover i will have control over the popover , but i need to manually close when user opens this popover and does not do any things on the popover(eg: clicking outside the popover).

Any idea about this ?  I used "popover-trigger='focus'",but it doesnt allows me to write into the input field (whenever hover the popover it closes)

Comment: Possible duplicate, the solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512748/hide-angular-ui-bootstrap-popover-when-clicking-outside-of-it) with a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/K7cYQSDEBS3cHvDfJNLI?p=preview)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't know which version of angular-ui boostrap you are using, but I'm using the latest (1.1.1) and adding this do the trick:

> `popover-trigger="outsideClick"`

**You can see in this demo.**

[popover close when click outside](http://plnkr.co/edit/aX9ZwiLwDEONUAIVNquE?p=preview)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't know why, but this not work for me (I've checked version), but `popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"` works...

Comment: In versions 2.x.x, you must use popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" (note the single quote within the double quote)

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't read comments :-) Based on @kuanyui comment if it dosen't work with the accepted answer try to add simple cotes `'`

```
popover-trigger=" 'outsideClick' "
```