# What does bootstrap use for checking click outside in dropdown.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I looked at the bootstrap code for `dropdown.js` in github repo and would like to know what do they use to handle click outside/elsewhere functionality ?

If anyone can post an answer with a diagram for understanding, that would be very helpful..

Comment: I don't know the answer for this one, but if I had to guess it be that they use `$('body').on('click', function(e) { // hide dropdown unless e.target includes the dropdown`.  Here's a similar issue that has to do with popovers, but is about the same concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703093/how-to-dismiss-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-by-clicking-outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of `dropdown.js`, when the dropdown is opened, `toggle()` is executed and they add a backdrop `<div>` on the page that covers the entire screen behind it.  The new div gets a `click` event that calls `clearMenus()`.

Comment: can you also point out the repository code lines and paste a link here too. That would be very helpful for reading and research. @haferje

Comment: It isn't real helpful to other people to list the line numbers, as the files will change over time, but for the code as of today, you can start [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/027b7efd792f4fab065bc6e71d8d2573cd13cadb/js/dropdown.js#L71L74).