# Close bootstrap popover when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Similar question already asked but not for this example.

Here we have the code for the popover:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="popover_test">Popover Example</a>
<!-- POPOVER -->
<div id="content" class="hidden">
  Contents
</div>
<div id="title" class="hidden">
  Title
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".popover_test").popover({
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      return $("#content").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      return $("#title").html();
    }
});
```

***What is the approch in order to disappear it when i click outside of the popover ?***

Here a JSFIDDLE to test it online:
https://jsfiddle.net/C5GBU/1772/

```js
$(".popover_test").popover({
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      return $("#content").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      return $("#title").html();
    }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="popover_test">Popover Example</a>
<!-- POPOVER -->
<div id="content" class="hidden">
  Contents
</div>
<div id="title" class="hidden">
  Title
</div>
```

Thank's.

Comment: The HTML that you provided is only what you have to put in your DOM. Additional elements get created when the popover actually gets generated. Use your developer tools in the browser of your choice, and find what that element is that gets created as your "background" and put a listener in for that.

Comment: Please check my updated solution

Comment: Seems like people are copying answers from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703093/how-to-dismiss-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-by-clicking-outside

Comment: I tried to hide .popover class but not resolved the problem ! `$('body').on('click', function (e) { $(".popover").hide(); });`

Comment: I think I have the solution for you.  Please check my edited answer again.

Comment: Problem not solved yet ! when i click on the content of the popover nothing work.

Comment: Hi Mac Ben,  Right now my example will let you create the popover, and whenever you click anywhere but the popover it will disappear.  If you click the popover it will not disappear.  This was the question correct?

Comment: No, the question is like mentionned in the title ! when you click outside of the popover this one will disappear, but if you click in, will not disappear ! in your first example you given a solution for a text popover, your second example popover disappear whenever you click, the third and final example, nothing work if i click on the content (Popover disappear when i click on the title).

Comment: stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed. This not a solution since it disable any parent event.

Comment: In your example there is no functionality in the popover.

Comment: What do you mean ? i am using popover's twitter bootstrap functionality.

Comment: Yes bit within the popover you are not specifying any functionality. Therefore when you click it noting will happen.

Comment: Anywhy, the popover i want it like it is, but the only problem is the one i posted here :) thank you for your efforts, hope someone can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code -

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
 });
```

Comment: This not work for html example (Your code will work for simple popover), already tried it before i ask this question, anywhy thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Once again I have made an edit: https://jsfiddle.net/C5GBU/1775/

```
$(".popover_test").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $("#content").html();
  },
  title: function() {
    return $("#title").html();
  }
}).on('click', function(e) {
  $('.popover-content').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.popover_test').each(function() {
    //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
    //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover_test').has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(this).popover('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

Please let me know if this works

Comment: Please read my question ! (My example is an HTML popover and not simple one - text).

Comment: The update not solved the problem since when i click on the popover this one will disappear ... i need it to disappear only when clicking outside.

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found on [11703093](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703093/how-to-dismiss-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-by-clicking-outside)

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
$('[data-toggle="popover"],[data-original-title]').each(function () {
    //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
    //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {                
        (($(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover')||{}).inState||{}).click = false  // fix for BS 3.3.6
    }

});
```

});

Comment: If this is a duplicate flag as duplicate