# Cannot close bootstrap popover with a dynamic content on outside click - jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have here a popover with a dynamic content which shows up when I click the popover button. I want to close it when I also click on another area of the page. However, the popover only closes when I click the popover button.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-post" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Post/Lock">
    Post/Lock
</a>
```

I do not set the `data-content` on my HTML code. I set it on the js

```
$("#btn-post").click(function() {
    $("#btn-post").attr("data-content", var_dynamic_content);
    $('#btn-post').popover('show');
});
```

I have tried following some codes answered in this post

> [How to dismiss a Twitter Bootstrap popover by clicking outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703093/how-to-dismiss-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-by-clicking-outside)

but nothing there seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer really is similar to the one you mention in your question... Except that it is for Twitter‑Bootstrap (Bootstrap 4).

The difference seems to be that there is no `in` class.

I did not test it for all use case... But this snippet works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var var_dynamic_content = "Hello!";

  $("#btn-post").click(function() {
    $("#btn-post").attr("data-content", var_dynamic_content);
    $('#btn-post').popover('show');
  });

  $(document).click(function(e){
    // If the click occurs on #button-post or the popover itself --> exit!
    if(e.target == $("#btn-post")[0] || $(e.target).parents(".popover").length > 0){return;}
    $('#btn-post').popover('hide');
  });

});  // END ready
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-post" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Post/Lock">
    Post/Lock
</a>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BPLxGv?editors=1011)

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Good thing the popover only closes when clicked outside and not on the button and popover itself which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $('#btn-post').popover('hide');
});
```