# Select2 in Popover remove of element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I want to use select2 in a bootstrap popover for multiple selection.
Selection works fine.

[image]

But when I click on x to remove some element, the popover closes itself and only the selection stays.
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent popover dismiss when click

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
   $('[data-toggle="popover"],[data-original-title]').each(function () {
    //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
    //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {                
        (($(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover')||{}).inState||{}).click = false  // fix for BS 3.3.6
    }

   });
});
```

you can see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857326/3344953