# Closing dropdown menus when a user clicks outside using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create dropdown menus which open on click. This is done by adding the `.active` class to the `.dropdown-trigger.on-click` class elements which basically displays the menu. So far, everything works, but I don't really understand how I can close an opened dropdown menu when the user clicks anywhere outside of the opened menu. So far, my code looks like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-trigger.on-click").forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    })
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu ul > li.dropdown-menu-content {
    padding: 0.6rem 1.2rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu ul > li.dropdown-menu-divider {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.2rem;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 12rem;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
}
.dropdown .dropdown-trigger.on-click.active + .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-trigger on-click">Pick your weapon <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-menu-content">
                Weapons
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-menu-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sword</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Axe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bow</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-trigger on-click">Pick your class <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-menu-content">
                Classes
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-menu-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fighter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thief</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ninja</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note: When a user clicks on an opened menu, the menu should not close. It should only close when a user clicks outside of the opened menu.**

How can I do this using plain Javascript? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect click outside element (vanilla JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188654/detect-click-outside-element-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: When you solve your problem, do not forget to remove you event listener upon closing the dropdown you don't want these things to hang...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add a click to your document that checks if the button is being clicked. If not, it will check if there is an active dropdown and make it inactive.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Return if clicking on trigger
    if (event.target.matches('.dropdown-trigger')) {
      return;
    }

    document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-trigger.active").forEach(function(elem) {
       elem.classList.remove('active');
    })

}, false);
```

Comment: This works but the menu closes even if a click is made inside the menu. Any way to fix that with your implementation?

Comment: You can update the return conditional to check for the `li` or the `a` that are in the dropdown: `if (event.target.matches('.dropdown-trigger') || event.target.matches('li, a'))`