# Why blur and focus doesn't work on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, safari

I have simple button like that:

```
<button class="emoji-button-container" onblur="APP.hideEmojiContainer()" onclick="APP.toggleEmojiContainer()">
```

On Chrome both event works perfectly.

On Safari onclick event works without any problem, but onblur event doesn't get triggered. Also element.blur() function doesn't trigger onblur event.
I need it to work on Safari just like on Chrome, so what can I do? what's problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems Safari doesn't focus button element on click. So, according to [definition](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onblur.asp), onblur attribute fires the moment that the element loses focus. Element is not focused => onblur doesn't fire.

One of the solution could be manually apply `button.focus()` after click.

Another one is to attach `click` event on `document` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188654/detect-click-outside-element-vanilla-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

On Safari, buttons may not be focused on click (and because they do not focus, they do not trigger blur)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus

You can focus the button using javascript though

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function clickFunc(event) {
                console.log(event, 'click');
                event.target.focus();// Add me
            };

            function blurFunc(event) {
                console.log(event, 'blur');
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button class="emoji-button-container" onblur="blurFunc(event)" onclick="clickFunc(event)"></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Safari settings that are not enabled by default:
•   Go to Safari > Preferences.

- Click on the Advanced tab.
- Check the box at the bottom that says "Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage."