# Determine if click event source comes from thead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, onclick, dom-events

I've been at this for awhile now with no luck so I thought I'd throw something up on SO.

I need the function of a click event in and Angular directive to execute only if the source comes from the `tbody` not the `thead`. I've tried a number of routes to get this information, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. Here is my latest/best attempt. Will give you and idea what I'm going for:

```
/* Linker for the directive */
var linker = function (scope, elm, attrs) {  
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        elm.find('table tbody tr.uib-weeks td button span.text-info').closest('tr').find('button').addClass('chosenReportWeek');
    }, 1000); // This is a hack until we can find the proper load/render event           

    elm.on('click', function(event) {
        if(event.target.parent.indexOf('thead') === -1){
            elm.find('table tbody tr.uib-weeks button.active').closest('tr').find('button').addClass('chosenReportWeek');
        }                
    });
};
```

Comment: `if ( $(event.target).closest('tbody').length ) {...`

Comment: Had to change it to `'thead` in the `.closest` but it works. thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect click inside/outside of element with single event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660633/detect-click-inside-outside-of-element-with-single-event-handler)

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax below:

```
if($(event.target).closest('thead').length === 0)
```