# how to hide a specific div when clicking anywhere on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a search result div which have contains search result list items according to user's search. but i want to hide that result div when user click any where on the screen.

**here is my search div code:**

```
<div id="user_search">
    <div class="inpt-head-place" style="width:9em;">
        <?php echo form_open( '',[ 'class'=>' navbar-left navbar-change','id'=>'search_form']) ?>
        <?php echo form_input([ 'type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control form-media search_user_bar','placeholder'=>'Search Here','name'=>'search']); ?>
    <div id="search_result" class="search_result"> </div>

    </div>
    <div class="inpt-head-place" style="width: 20px;">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-resize" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_here"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here is a Snap of search Bar with their results:**

[image: And here is a Snap of search Bar with their results]

Kindly suggest me.. Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660633/detect-click-inside-outside-of-element-with-single-event-handler you can check if the click is inside that div if it is do nothing, if it isnt hide the div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the clicked element, or any child element is the one clicked or the child of the one clicked by binding the click to the `document` or `body`:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$('#search_result').is(e.target) && $('#search_result').has(e.target).length === 0){
    $('#search_result').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, it will hide `search_result` div when you click outside of `search_result`.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#search_result"); //ID of dic you want to hide 
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using JS by wrapping the body in a div (or just use the body) and then adding a on click event listener to that div, if the body is clicked just close the search results.
somthing like,

```
document.getElementById('body-div').addEventListener("click", function(){
    //set style of search result to display: none or hide in some reasonable way
});
```