# Detect click inside an element with delegation and when the element is selected by its class name

Tags: javascript

How can I detect if a click is inside an element whose listener is selected by a class?

For example, I have a few elements with class name "my-class":

```
<div class="my-class">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <p>World</p>
</div>
<div class="my-class">
    <a href="">Click</a>
    <a href="">Here</a>
</div>
```

If I only listen to the class, it won't work if the click is made on the inner elements:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if(event.target.classList.contains("my-class") {
        // 
    }
});
```

How can I also detect click on any of the elements inside?

I found the following question, but it works only for a single element who was selected by an id and without delegation: [Detect click inside/outside of element with single event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660633/detect-click-inside-outside-of-element-with-single-event-handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Element::closest()` to check whether the clicked element inside `my-class` or `my-class` itself:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if(event.target.closest(".my-class")) {
        console.log('my-class clicked!');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <p>World</p>
</div>
<div class="my-class">
    <a href="">Click</a>
    <a href="">Here</a>
</div>
```